# How to delete a work item in TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-power-tools

This has been asked before but I'm struggling to find a way to delete a work item in Team Foundation Server. This looks promising:
http://devmatter.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/deleting-work-items-in-tfs-ui.html. But no luck with it so far.

First tried the following command:

`witadmin destroywi /collection:"https://<<my TFS collection>>" /id:1223`

It returned `Unable to destroy work item(s) 1223. TF237090: Does not exist or access is denied.`

Unfortunately I can't download the "Delete Work Item" utility mentioned in the article due to work's internet restrictions as it's on Skydrive. Also tried the "TEK workitem" extension (mentioned in a comment at the bottom) but this won't let me either as I'm not a Project Collection Administrator.

Am I doomed to be stuck with this work item forever or is there any other way?

Comment: Have you tried running that command as a server admin?

Comment: @DanPuzey Please forgive my ignorance but how would I do that?

Comment: You need to have TFS Admin permissions to do that.

Comment: Oh just seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908.aspx So it seems I just can't delete work items as I'm not a member of the Project Administrators security group and can't change the permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's a little annoying. Setting the item state to "Removed" will at least hide it from view.