# How to delete a VSTS/TFS work item

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to delete some dummy test cases and user stories and I found the [official doc](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work) to do that. Seems I need to use a cli tool called `witadmin`.

They mention an **incorrect path** to that tool. I have Visual Studio 2017 installed and found it at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

Then I tried to run this command, which tells which work items to delete from which collection.

`.\witadmin.exe destroywi /collection:https://<ORGANIZATION>.visualstudio.com/<PROJECT> /id:405,440,403`

A dialog box appeared for me to login, I filled with my user and pass and got this error after a while:

```
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://ORG.visualstudio.com/PROJ.
Team Foundation Server Url: https://ORG.visualstudio.com/PROJ.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

The pass is correct, the server is online. So it can be only the TFS name. What should also be correct, right? I used the same URL of the project. I also tried adding `/defaultcollection` but then I was unable to pass the login dialog.

I saw this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921309/how-to-delete-a-work-item-in-tfs-2012) suggesting that "you need to have TFS Admin permissions" -- which I don't have.

Any ideas? Should I give up and change the state of the items to "Removed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to these steps to permanently delete work items:

1. Go to Work page
2. Right click a work item > Delete
3. Click Recycle Bin button

[image]

4. Right click a work item > permanently delete

Delete work item via witadmin tool:

```
witadmin destroywi /collection: https://ORG.visualstudio.com /id:405,440,403
```

More information, you can refer to: [Delete work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items#delete-work-items)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use WITADMIN for this. If you have the "Delete work items" permission, you can drag and drop work items into a Recycle Bin and delete them from there.

With WITADMIN, you shouldn't include the project in the path.